# Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found (Laravel + Heroku)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, heroku, laravel-5, amazon-s3

connect my laravel 5.4 application in heroku with aws s3 to save and display images that I upload with a dashboard.

In local I have no problem with uploading and viewing the images, even these are stored in the bucket I made. But when I set up aws in heroku to do tests there, I get the error: **Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter'**

I already removed and reinstalled the package from composer, I do not know why the error does not appear in my local environment.

thank you very much.

Comment: How do you deploy your app to Heroku? Are dependencies even installed with `composer install` during deployment, or is the content of the `vendor` directory synchronized to production otherwise?

Comment: Can you share the content of your `composer.json`?

Comment: it is already more than a year now, did not find right answer lol?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

you forgot to install the required library

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3
```

good luck

Comment: We're using **Laravel 8.34** which is locked to `league/flysystem:^1.1`, and prevented us to use it like above.
Luckily here is the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65002651/697579
`composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3:"^1.0"`

Comment: I had to run it with the `-W` flag: `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "~1.0" -W`

Answer (score 42):

For laravel 8 use

```
 composer require --with-all-dependencies league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^1.0"
```

Comment: Why to use v1 when last version is 2.1.0 as of August 2021?

Comment: When I used this, the 2nd version was not released yet

Comment: great help, solve my problem in 2 minutes!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well with Laravel 9 and PHP 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

I solved mine with

```
composer require guzzlehttp/psr7 "1.8.1"
```

to first downgrade from version 2.0.0 as the was sdk package doesn't yet support version 2.0.0.. then

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "~1.0" --update-with-all-dependencies
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Laravel docs:

```
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem
```

You need this dependancy

```
composer require --with-all-dependencies league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^1.0"
```

Comment: Good idea to check the docs, because it will depend on which version of Laravel you are using!

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 9 solution

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^3.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

@localheinz When I did the deploy I run: **composer install**

But in heroku the packages install them from the console that has the heroku dashboard.

But when I want to add or remove the package **league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3** the following message comes out:

**Package listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.**

So I think there's a cache in between, because everything works fine for me.

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.4",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.6",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "unisharp/laravel-ckeditor": "^4.6",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]           
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I had the same issue and tried many solutions but nothing worked with me. Finally I found out that `flysystem-aws-s3-v2` is in composer.lock although I was using `flysystem-aws-s3-v3` with the command: `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3` which doesn't change anything in `composer.lock` so what I did is that I removed `vendor` folder and `composer.lock` file and run `composer install` and that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

My case was a bit tougher, I had to upgrade a couple of related dependencies in order to have it up and running. Mainly I upgraded `aws/aws-sdk-php` to the version the composer mentioned when I ran:
`composer require --with-all-dependencies league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^1.0"`.