# league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 on Laravel 8 other packages require lower version

Tags: laravel, composer-php

When running `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3` I get:

`league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[2.0.0, ..., 2.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^2.0.0 -> found league/flysystem[2.0.0-alpha.1, ..., 2.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 1.1.3 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.`

In my `composer.json` there is no mention of `league/flysystem`, but it does appear in my `composer.lock` as `"league/flysystem": "^1.1",`. It looks like I have a few packages (like `spatie/laravel-backup`) that have this as an dependancy.

How do I proceed? I'm not sure how to update a package that other packages have as an dependancy, and that these other packages have also fixed to a specific version.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

As you've found already: `spatie/laravel-backup` is not yet compatible with `league/flysystem` v2 (which is pretty new, it got released... yesterday!).

Simply require the "old" version of that AWS package through `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3:"^1.0"`.

After all, this is not a problem of Laravel itself.

Answer (score 30):

I am using the latest version of laravel V8.4.0 (JULY 2021)

I solve this by:

1. Deleting `composer.lock` in the root folder of the project
2. running `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3:"~1.0"`

Answer (score 18):

For Laravel 8 use

```
composer require --with-all-dependencies league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^1.0"
```

Comment: You recovered my peace. Namaste.

Answer (score 4):

It is a problem with Laravel. Laravel v8 does not support `league/flysystem` v2 yet. v9 will be shipped with a support for it: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/33612

Comment: I just installed Laravel 9 with league/flysystem by doing composer require league/flysystem and it installs fine.

Answer (score 4):

For those on Laravel 9, you'll need to upgrade to v3.0 instead.

> composer require -W league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^3.0"

After deleting compose.lock

Comment: I was on the incognito window while working. I had to copy the link to my normal windows tab and logged in to give you a like cos you saved my hours of trying to fix this in Laravel 10.

Answer (score 1):

for **laravel 9** :

1. Deleting `composer.lock` in the root folder of the project
2. running  `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`