# Uploading files to S3. Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, composer-php, flysystem, thephpleague

I'm trying to upload files to S3 but I'm getting the error:

`Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found`

I have run this command:

`composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3:~1.0`

I have ran `composer update`

`composer info` shows this:

[image]

My `composer.json` shows this:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "larapack/config-writer": "^1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
```

I'm lost. Unsure what is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found (Laravel + Heroku)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45619465/class-league-flysystem-awss3v3-awss3adapter-not-found-laravel-heroku)

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved to trigger that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have version 2.0.2 installed. Flysystem was recently re-written, so I think you need to install version 1 for it to be compatible with Laravel (until Laravel updates the underlying version of Flysystem it uses).

Try running:

```
composer require "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3=^1.0"
```